# Prove identity composed of floor functions

Tags: number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

How to prove:
$$\left\lfloor \frac{x+2}{6}\right\rfloor -\left\lfloor \frac{x+3}{6}\right\rfloor +\left\lfloor \frac{x+4}{6}\right\rfloor =\left\lfloor \frac{x}{2}\right\rfloor -\left\lfloor \frac{x}{3}\right\rfloor$$

where $x\in \mathbb{R}$.
I think it is problem made by Ramanujan, but do not have the source.

Comment: For next time, make sure to show whether or not you have attempted to solve a problem yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: write $x= 6k+r$ where $o\leq r <6$ and $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. Then we have:

$$\left\lfloor \frac{x+2}{6}\right\rfloor -\left\lfloor \frac{x+3}{6}\right\rfloor +\left\lfloor \frac{x+4}{6}\right\rfloor = 
k + \underbrace{\left\lfloor \frac{r+2}{6}\right\rfloor -\left\lfloor
\frac{r+3}{6}\right\rfloor +\left\lfloor
\frac{r+4}{6}\right\rfloor}_{A}$$

and

$$\left\lfloor \frac{x}{2}\right\rfloor -\left\lfloor \frac{x}{3}\right\rfloor = k +\underbrace{\left\lfloor \frac{r}{2}\right\rfloor -\left\lfloor
\frac{r}{3}\right\rfloor}_{B}$$

Comment: So we end up with the same identity but instead of "x" we have "r".

Comment: Yes, and now consider the cases for $r$. If $r>4$ then $A=1-1+1=1$ and $B=2-1=1$, and so on...

Comment: Or just test for all possible r $0<=r<=5$. I see...

Comment: No, no, no. Be careful, $r$ is not an integer.

Comment: Oh, silly of me.

Comment: So I do not understand your comment about r>4.

Comment: I just give an example, now you have to take the other case, $3\leq r\leq 4$...