# Simplifying expression composed of floor functions

Tags: number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

We are given expression:
$$\left\lfloor \frac{x+2}{6}\right\rfloor -\left\lfloor \frac{x+3}{6}\right\rfloor +\left\lfloor \frac{x+4}{6}\right\rfloor$$
Simplify it so that it contains minimal number of floor functions.
How to do that? Even Mathematica cannot do it. Although we know it can be done as can be seen [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2506218/prove-identity-composed-of-floor-functions).

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hlisuxsg5z $$\\CAN  $$YOU simplify more  ?  please look at the figure .

Comment: The point is to simplify the expression not to plot its graph.